# How to manually add a delayed_job in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a Mailer that when executed, submits the following job.

*Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 189ce295-1da8-47f5-9933-1b5657554731) to DelayedJob(mailers) with arguments: "UserMailer", “register_success", "deliver_now", gid://myapp/User/1, gid://myapp/Order/294*

If I wanted to manually place queue this exact job into the table for ActiveJob to execute, what methods are available to me? Would I have to run the exact SQL statements or is there some method I can just call with the arguments like:

Queue("UserMailer", “register_success", "deliver_now", gid://myapp/User/1, gid://myapp/Order/294)

I should also add I don't have access to the UserMailer class.

Comment: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#custom-jobs

Comment: Thanks, however I'm not clear on how I then tell delayed job to add "UserMailer", "register_success" and "deliver_now". I don't have access to the UserMailer object so I can't do UserMailer.deliver as in the examples.

Comment: @AbM where would you define that `Struct`? My `enqueue` method cannot find it.

Comment: @XMLSlayer I put all custom jobs in `app/jobs` in their own class that inherits from `Struct`.

Comment: @AbM so in my example how would this look?

`UserMailer = Struct.new() do
  def perform
      #what goes here?
  end
end`

Is something like this a correct start? I'm still not clear how the documentation on the page connects to what I want to do...

Comment: Can you post how the entry looks like in your delayed jobs table? In your console, you can do `Delayed::Job.find(id).inspect`